# Why does the time function and print() execute before the label is created in the Tkinter window

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

```
def createLabel():
    l = label(text='Label Created')
    l.grid(row=10, column=3)
    time.sleep(5)
    print('Label Created')

b = Button(text='Click to create a label', command=createLabel)
```

Output:
After 5 seconds 
printed: Label Created
Then the label appears

**
How to make the label appear on the window first then print() the "Label Created message"

Please help me with this..
**

Comment: They don't execute before. It's simply that the UI doesn't update until `createLabel` returns and you're explicitly telling the program to sleep 5 seconds. There are countless questions on this site related to updating widgets, have you done any research? Perhaps if you can share what you searched for, we can edit some of the questions or answers so that they are more discoverable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `after(ms, func, *args)`. Here is an example of your case.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk


def createLabel():
    l = Label(text='Label Created')
    l.pack(side=BOTTOM)
    b.after(5000, print, 'Label created')


root = tk.Tk()
b = Button(root,text='Click to create a label', command=createLabel)
b.pack(side=TOP)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You don't really need to make a `prnt` function, arguments to the callback function can be passed to `after(ms, func, *args)` method straight. So it should be like `b.after(5000, print, 'Label Created')`.